# SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle 11g version 1.1

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, string-concatenation

Would it be possible to construct SQL in Oracle 11g version 1.1 to concatenate column values from multiple rows?

The following is an example:

```
Table A

dName cName amount  type
  A     B     100   water
  A     B     200   house
  A     C     400   air
  A     B     300   water
```

output of the SQL should be -

```
dName   CName  totalAmount  count      type
A        B       600         3     water,house
A        C       400         1         air
```

remove duplicate type also distinct like..

So basically the type column for output result is a concatenation of the type values from Table A with sum(amount) group by dName and cName.

Any help with the SQL? I am using Oracle 11g version 1.1. So the listagg() function is not working.Actually I don't want to use collect() function. I mean don't need to change the current table structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `wm_concat()`, an unsupported function:

```
select dName, CName, totalAmount, "count", wm_concat("type") as "type"
from a
group by dName, CName, totalAmount, "count";
```

[Here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php#wm_concat) is a good resource on the many other ways to get this done in Oracle.

EDIT:

If you don't want to write your own function and you have just a handful of things to bring together, you can use a conditional aggregation method:

```
select dName, CName, totalAmount, "count",
       (max(case when seqnum = 1 then "type" end) ||
        max(case when seqnum = 2 then ','||"type" end) ||
        max(case when seqnum = 3 then ','||"type" end) ||
        max(case when seqnum = 4 then ','||"type" end) ||
        max(case when seqnum = 5 then ','||"type" end)
       ) as "type"
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by dName, CName, totalAmount, "count"
                                order by "type"
                               ) as seqnum
     ) a
group by dName, CName, totalAmount, "count";
```

Comment: 11.1 am using. Not supporting wm_concat

Answer (score 0):

try this query in oracle 11g:

```
select t1.dName,t1.CName,t2.TotalAmount,t2.count,t1.type from
(select dName,CName,LISTAGG(TYPE,',') within group(order by TYPE)as type
from
(select UNIQUE dName,CName,type from A)
group by dName, CName)t1,
(select dName,CName,sum(amount) as TotalAmount,count(amount) as count
from A group by dName, CName)t2
where t1.dName||t1.CName = t2.dName||t2.CName order by CName;
```

if you can't use listagg try this query:

```
select t1.dName,t1.CName,t2.TotalAmount,t2.count,t1.type from
(select dName,CName,rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement(e,TYPE||',')).extract ('//text()'), ',')  as type
from
(select UNIQUE dName,CName,type from A)
group by dName, CName)t1,
(select dName,CName,sum(amount) as TotalAmount,count(amount) as count
from A group by dName, CName)t2
where t1.dName||t1.CName = t2.dName||t2.CName order by CName;
```